# my external hd keeps unmounting when the computer is idle over a long period

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard

i have mac os 10.6(snow leopard) and my external hard drive keeps unmounting when the computer is idle for a long period. how can i fix this its anoying?

Answer (score 1):

Try System Preferences -> Energy Saver -> Put the hard disks to sleep when possible.

That should stop the disks spinning down, and stop them unmounting.